# SQL like command failing in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, sql-like, unary-operator

I have the following code, which i want to compare two strings (varchars).

If item.item_name contains the string equipment_type anywhere, i want it to return the record.

But i recieved a error, stating INVALID NUMBER on the  upper('%' + equipment_type + '%') command.

```
select * from equipment_type
join item on upper(item.item_name) like upper('%' + equipment_type + '%')
```

I realize the issue is adding the wildcard strings to the variable equipment_type.
Does anyone know how to get this wildcard comparison to work?

Comment: Oracle uses `+` for numeric and date math only. For string concatenation, use double bars (`||`): `... like upper('%' || equipment_type || '%')`.

Comment: @EdGibbs - You should put that as an answer..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - I did consider doing that, waffling between "yes, it's a real answer" and "no, it's a pretty trivial answer" (though not, of course, to the OP Jordan). Now that you've got me thinking about it, I'll add it as an answer in case someone else finds it useful. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @EdGibbs +1 for waffling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* I originally answered this in the comments. Since then, it was suggested that I post the solution here as a "real" answer. Here goes...

Oracle uses + for numeric and date math only. For string concatenation, use double bars (`||`):

```
select * from equipment_type
join item on upper(item.item_name) like upper('%' || equipment_type || '%')

                       The only changes are here  ^^   ... and here ^^
```